# Detect unsaved changes in DataGridView on form closing VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datasource, formclosing

Hi I have a DataGridView that has a data table for it's data source. I have a function that uses the DataTable.GetChanges() method and it works beautifully when I run the function while the form is still active; however, I put that function in the form closing event so that it will check for unsaved changes when the form is closed, but for some reason it always comes back with no changes when I run it from the from closing method.

I am guessing that the data source is getting disposed automatically on closing before my function runs to get the changes.

Is there anyway to prevent the data source from getting disposed? I have tried doing e.Cancel=True when in the form closing event and then running my function and it still doesn't work.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how/why is the app closing down. there is more that one way and not all of them invoke those events

Comment: just when you click the red x in the top right corner of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out it only didn't save the change when I typed something into the DataGrid without hitting enter to commit that edit. It actually had nothing to do with the form closing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are in the  Handles Me.FormClosing event? I know I had difficulty with the same thing when I used OnFormClose event. My program works fine using the Me.FormClosing all I do is check

if dataset.has changes then
      CallSaveLogic()
end if

It should be the same for a datatable.

Comment: Yes I am using Me.FormClosing. I am quite stumped on this.

Comment: Is there anywhere that you are accepting changes on the datatable? If before this code is hit someone has run a datatable.acceptchanges() then your changes won't be found. Other then that You would probably need to check the scope of the datatable you are using.

Comment: I would also check the values of the table when debugging. You should be able to hit a breakpoint and see that your table still exists at that point. Do the Shift+F9 in visual studio and look at your table as long as it isn't null.

Comment: The accept changes method is only getting called once after I save the data; however, I put a breakpoint on it just to be sure it is getting run when my form closes and it is NOT.

Comment: Also my dataTable has been declared Privately in the Public Class definition that way it is accessible form wide.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to add a comment to your response. But you can peform an end edit on your datagridview before it attempts to see if there are changes. It will let you save without necessarily hitting enter or tab.